# Как вставить в PHP-код большую HTML-форму

Tags: php, html

У меня есть большая HTML-форма, куда я должен вставить информацию из БД в виде значений по умолчанию. Я попытался вывести её через echo в php-файле, но вышло не очень читабельно + появилась ошибка:
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''"><br>' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'`
Вот сама форма:

```
echo '<form method="post" action="change.php">
    Название: <input type="text" name="title" value="'.$result['title'].'"><br>
    Цена: <input type="text" name="price" value="'.$result['price']'"><br>
    Краткое описание: <textarea name="mini_description" rows="5" cols="33" 
    value="'.$result['mini_description'].'"></textarea><br>
    Тип товара: <select name="select"> <option value="signaling">Сигнализации</option><br>
                <option value="video">Видеокамеры</option></select><br>
    Категория: <input type="text" name="brand" value="'.$result['brand'].'"><br>
    ID категории: <input type="text" name="brand_id" value="'.$result['brand_id'].'"><br>
    Полное описание: <textarea name="description" rows="10" cols="70" 
    value="'.$result['description'].'"></textarea><br>
    Краткие характеристики: <textarea name="mini_features" rows="5" cols="33" 
    value="'.$result['mini_features'].'"></textarea><br>
    Характеристики: <textarea name="features" rows="10" cols="70" 
    value="'.$result['features'].'"></textarea><br>
    Количество: <input type="text" name="count" value="'.$result['count'].'"><br>
    Изображение (URL): <input type="text" name="image" value="'.$result['image'].'"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Сохранить"></form>';
```

Как можно это исправить? Какие ещё есть варианты соединить форму с PHP-переменными?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.ob-start.php

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.ob-get-clean.php

Так же, у textarea нет value, значение нужно устанавливать внутри тега.

```
<?php
$form = ob_start();
?>
    <form method="post" action="change.php">
        Название: <input type="text" name="title" value="<?=$result['title']?>"><br>
        Цена: <input type="text" name="price" value="<?=$result['price']?>"><br>
        Краткое описание: <textarea name="mini_description" rows="5" cols="33" value="<?=$result['mini_description']?>"></textarea><br>
        Тип товара:
        <select name="select">
            <option value="signaling">Сигнализации</option><br>
            <option value="video">Видеокамеры</option>
        </select><br>
        Категория: <input type="text" name="brand" value="<?=$result['brand']?>"><br>
        ID категории: <input type="text" name="brand_id" value="<?=$result['brand_id']?>"><br>
        Полное описание: <textarea name="description" rows="10" cols="70"><?=$result['description']?></textarea><br>
        Краткие характеристики: <textarea name="mini_features" rows="5" cols="33"><?=$result['mini_features']?></textarea><br>
        Характеристики: <textarea name="features" rows="10" cols="70"><?=$result['features']?></textarea><br>
        Количество: <input type="text" name="count" value="<?=$result['count']?>"><br>
        Изображение (URL): <input type="text" name="image" value="<?=$result['image']?>"><br>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Сохранить">
    </form>
<?php
$form = ob_get_clean();
echo $form;
?>
```

Comment: Cпасибо огромное! Очень помогло!

Answer (score 2):

Изучите HEREDOC и NOWDOC

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc

и не мучайтесь с этими экранированиями и кавычками в строках.

А еще, весь этот код может быть записан вне `echo`, если это вывод в шаблоне представления происходит

Comment: Cпасибо большое! Знал про HEREDOC и NOWDOC, но тут почему-то не подумал о них.